# .ipToCountry in MySQL Query wont work

Tags: php, mysql

when i try to use this code:

```
function ipToCountry($ip){ $info = file_get_contents("http://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/$ip");
list($a, $b) = explode('country:        ', $info);
return  substr($b,0,2);}

echo "" .ipToCountry($ip); // This works, it writes country from IP
```

But when i try to use there:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`.`klikovi` (`id`, `reklamaid`, `ip`, `vrijeme`, `ok`, `country`) VALUES (NULL, '$id', '$ip', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', 'echo "" .ipToCountry($ip);');");
```

I got error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.'
```

I tried to remove '.' but then .ipToCountry dont work at all...
Can you guys help me with that? how i can write Country in MySQL query...

EDIT:
I found answer, i used:

```
$c = "" .ipToCountry($ip); echo $c;
```

Now i can just use $c in mysql query :) Thanks all anyway

Comment: You do not need echo `'1', '.ipToCountry($ip).')"`

Comment: I removed "SOLVED" from the title; that's not how things are done on Stack. You can either post your own answer, or delete the question. The choice is yours.

Comment: Try `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`.`klikovi` (`id`, `reklamaid`, `ip`, `vrijeme`, `ok`, `country`) VALUES (NULL, '$id', '$ip', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', 'ipToCountry($ip)'");`

Comment: Did it solved @Mc Filip Hope it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you cannot put that echo in the sql statement like that. I would use more verbose code which often makes this easier to see (especially if using a friendly IDE)

```
$theIPCountry = ipToCountry($ip);

$qry = "INSERT INTO `table`.`klikovi`
(`id`, `reklamaid`, `ip`, `vrijeme`, `ok`, `country`)
VALUES
(NULL, $id, $ip, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1, $theIPCountry);"

$sql = mysql_query($qry);
```